# How do I enable BIGTIFF=YES option when using gdal_rasterize?

Tags: gis, raster, gdal, qgis, rasterizing

I am using the `Rasterize (write over existing raster)` tool within QGIS - however same question would apply if you were calling gdal from command line or python.

I am burning a vector feature into a raster with values based on a field in the attribute table.

All fine and working except when the destination raster is >4GB BigTiff rather than a regular geotiff. How do I use the bigtiff option mentioned in the error?

The error is:

```
'ERROR 1: TIFFAppendToStrip:Maximum TIFF file size exceeded. Use BIGTIFF=YES creation option.
```

Code is as follows:

```
gdal_rasterize -a burn_value -l shapefile_name C:/Users/Cate/Folder/shapefile_name.shp C:/Users/Cate/Folder/raster_name.tif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the creation options `-co`:

```
gdal_rasterize -a burn_value -l shapefile_name C:/Users/Cate/Folder/shapefile_name.shp C:/Users/Cate/Folder/raster_name.tif -co BIGTIFF=YES
```

Comment: This doesn't work as is in QGIS as it throws up the following error:


`ERROR 6: '-tr xres yres' or '-ts xsize ysize' is required.`

This is asking to specify the target resolution.

Comment: When I set the target resolution I get `Permission denied` so will play around with it some more to resolve this but it does appear to be trying to write the geotiff properly.

Answer (score 0):

In the advanced parameters you can enter it as a key just like you would enter the COMPRESS option. Enter BIGTIFF for the key and YES for the value column.